# can i still get my code from tfs if i have not checked in my code?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS for source control. I am working on project since last 3 months smoothly. But from last month, I have not checked in my work and unfortunately my hard drive crash and i am unable to recover my code. So is there any possibility to recover my code from TFS?

Comment: So, you didn't check in for about 4 weeks??

Comment: yes i didn't  unfortunately -_-

Comment: Then I guess you just burned 4 week's work. Local changes are unknown to the remote repo.

Comment: Always shelve set the code!! Helps have a copy when the code isn't quite ready for checkin

Comment: yeah it was just a bad experience. i believe i will never do this mistake again mistakenly in future!

Comment: well, make your habit to check in after some major change or at day end

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT yes, i have just marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The following advice is applicable to every version control system ever created:

**Commit your changes to source control every single day**. If you're working on a long-term change that isn't done, then use branches.